# Can't build artifacts javaFX application with mvvmFX framework

Tags: javafx, java-8, mvvmfx

I cloned source code from https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX and trying to build artifact from module **mvvmfx-spring-boot** but when I run the jar from output nothing happen so I run it from cmd **java -jar xxx.jar** and it show **Error: Could not find or load main class de.saxsys.mvvmfx.spring.MvvmfxSpringApplication**.

I'm using Intellj 2020.3 to build artifact
May someone help me fix that

Comment: 1. Why are you doing this? 2. It is a [maven project](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/blob/develop/mvvmfx-spring-boot/pom.xml), so you should use maven to build the artifact, not Idea. 3. It is a library to be used as a dependency as shown in its [readme](https://github.com/sialcasa/mvvmFX/tree/develop/mvvmfx-spring-boot). 4.  Because it is a dependent library, you don't need to clone it and build it, it is already built and deployed to maven central.  5. The maven project does not create an executable jar file, so you can't execute that jar. 6. Java8 is obsolete, use Java17.

Comment: @jewelsea Thanks for your comment, I have a project using this lib and I want to build it to executable file but get the error so I tried to build the example project on it. The reason I am using java 8 is Intellj just support for jdk <= 8

Comment: "Intellj just support for jdk <= 8" -> that is incorrect, if they did that they would go out of business, which they assuredly are not.